# Which VueJS lifecycle hook must Asynchronous HTTP requests be called in?

Tags: asynchronous, vue.js, vuejs2, lifecycle, vue-resource

I'd like to know how before I render a page, I want to send an async GET request to my server to retrieve data and populate the properties in data. I heard the best way to do this is to call the function that sends this request in one of the three lifecycle hooks Vue js offers that operate before the DOM is rendered. The three are `beforeCreate()`, `created()`, `beforeMount()`. Which one must this request be called in ideally? And why?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> **TL;DR** in the general (and safe) case, use `created()`.

Vue's initialization code is executed synchronously.

Technically, any ASYNChronous code you run in `beforeCreate()`, `created()`, `beforeMount()` will only respond after ***all*** of those hooks finish. See demo:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  beforeCreate() {
    setTimeout(() => { console.log('fastest asynchronous code ever') }, 0);
    console.log('beforeCreate hook done');
  },
  created() {
    console.log('created hook done');
  },
  beforeMount() {
    console.log('beforeMount hook done');
  },
  mounted() {
    console.log('mounted hook done');
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  Check the console.
</div>
```

In other words, if you make an Ajax call in `beforeCreate()`, no matter how fast the API responds, the response will only be processed way later, way after the `created()` has been executed.

What should guide your decision, then?

- Need just to trigger a call as soon as possible?

  - Use `beforeCreate()`
  - Why?

    - It runs sooner than any of those hooks, but...
- Need to **read from or modify `data`** right away?

  - Use `created()`
  - Why?

    - [State is only initialized between `beforeCreate()` and `created()`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.5.16/dist/vue.js#L4613-L4617), so if you [**assign some data before `created()`, it would be lost**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/gxt6xr1p/).
- Need anything that is generated after `created()`?

  - Use `beforeMount()`
  - Why?

    - I don't know anything that isn't available at `created()` and is available at `beforeMount()` [**other than the compiled `this.$options.render`  render function**](https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/ow2Lrf1c/) (see [source as well](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/v2.5.16/dist/vue.js#L2739-L2765)), so this case must really be a rare situation.

Comment: Thank you, beginner vue developer here. Very helpful explanation. Cheers.

Comment: Another alternative pattern is described in this answer: [Is async/await available in Vue.js mounted?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53513789), where the API call is made in the `mounted` hook instead. Perform component setup in the prior hooks, and hide what you don't want shown with a flag that you only flip after the API call comes back. This has the likely effect of lowering your component's load time, which can help avoid slower, less responsive, and overall worse experiences for your user. The faster the page loads, even if you're still waiting for _some_ sections, the better!

Answer (score 13):

The vue-router docs have some advice for patterns to use when retrieving data from a server that is required for component render (see bottom for link).

To determine where to perform the GET request, they first ask if you want to navigate to the route **before** async GET request is initiated or **after**

If you want to fetch the data then navigate to the route (*before navigation*) then the docs suggest performing the async request in the `beforeRouteEnter()` guard on the incoming component making sure to call `next()` in `beforeRouteEnter()` once the async data request has been fulfilled. If you choose this pattern you will want to display some sort of loading indicator as the navigation to the route/rendering of the component will not occur until the data has been fetched.

If you want to navigate to the route then initiate the request (*after navigation*) then the docs suggest performing the request in the `created()` hook and using `v-if` to conditionally show either that the component is loading, an error has occurred, or the view once the data has arrived.

Highly recommend checking out the docs, they have code examples and its well written. 
https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/data-fetching.html#fetching-before-navigation

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned above, the key issue that exists in both Vue and React is, if you make a network request and the data arrives before the component is created, there is no instance to set the data to.

`beforeCreated` is similar to React's `componentWillMount`. You generally wouldn't want to execute a network request here because you might get your data back before the component exists. It's like setting `this.data = data` but there is no component, so `this` doesn't exist yet.

A better place in React is `componentDidMount`, but we don't care about that. In Vue, a better place is `created` because the component has been created already, so `this` exists.

Here is an example:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <span v-if="error">{{ error }}</span><br>
    I like:<br>
    {{ data }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      data: '',
      error: undefined,
    }
  },

  async created() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('/endpoint/stuff')
      this.data = response
    } catch (err) {
      this.error = err
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends.

> This depends what you want, for a User Experience. Do you want the route to display immediately, but show a loading spinner on this routes content?
>
> Or do you want to wait until data is fetched, THEN show the route? (which could give the illusion of a laggy application)
>
> If you want to do the first way I mentioned, then you could do it in the created hook of your component.

https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-is-the-best-hook-to-call-api-to-load-initialisation-data-for-a-component/15167/2