# Why "Error in render: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined" returned even data already available?

Tags: vue.js

I already initialize the data.

```
data () {
  return {
    current_product: {},
    current_ID: '',
  }
}
```

Then, I fetch data from a REST API on lifecycle **created** hook.

```
created () {
  var skuID = this.$store.state.selected_productSKU.productSKU_ID

  axios.get(`http://localhost:8081/api/products/${skuID}`)
    .then(response => {
      this.current_ID = response.data.product_ID
      this.current_product = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
      alert(e)
  })
}
```

And finally, I use computed property to get some value

```
// THIS JUST RETURN ['XL', 'M']
focusedProduct_SKUS_NoDupSizes () {
  var newArr = this.current_product.product_SKU.filter((sku, index, self) =>
    index === self.findIndex(t => (
      t.productSKU_size === sku.productSKU_size
    ))
  )
  var x = newArr.map(a => a.productSKU_size)
  return x
}
```

The vue instance show expected result

[image: Expected Result]

But if i call `{{ focusedProduct_SKUS_NoDupSizes }}` in template.

- It doesn't rendered.
- The browser return error `Error in render: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined"`

What is happening? My first guess is the `computed property` using the initial structure of `current_product` which is `{} empty object`. But isn't that how to initialize an object?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of:

```js
computed:
  // ...
  focusedProduct_SKUS_NoDupSizes () {
    var newArr = this.current_product.product_SKU.filter((sku, index, self) =>
                                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You should initialize `product_SKU` with an empty array:

```js
data () {
  return {
    current_product: {product_SKU: []}, // changed here
    current_ID: '',
  }
}
```

This is needed because the computed property will be executed right away, even before your Ajax gets a chance to return.

Declare it as empty so the computed doesn't throw an error. When the Ajax fulfills, it will recompute automatically.

Even though the Ajax is started at the `created()`, it won't return *before* the computed is executed for the first time. [More details about this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49581830/1850609).

Comment: Thank you. I understand now. :)
edit: its working too