# Vuejs Problems assigning value to a variable after a call to an api rest method

Tags: vue.js, async-await, axios

```
data: () => ({
    selectedDpto:null,
    listDepartamentos: []
}),
methods: {
    async listarDptos() {
        await this.$store
        .dispatch("gscentralemergencias/UBIGEO_FIND_ALL", paramsCustom)
        .then(res => {
          this.listDepartamentos = res === undefined ? [] : res;
          console.log('Bloque Result', this.listDepartamentos);
        })
        .catch(error => {
          if (error.response.status == 401 || error.response.status == 500 ) {
              this.$swal(
                error.response.data.errorMessage,
                "Ud. no tiene permitido esta función",
                "warning"
              );
            }
        });
    },
},
mounted() {
    this.listarDptos();
    console.log('Bloque Mounted', this.listDepartamentos);
}
```

When I show the array in console.info(this.listDepartamentos);   it returns it to me empty, what can I do? I updated to see how he is responding, even though the method is called first, what is below is shown first.

[image]

Comment: Check if you have response and the data format, on network activity from your browser.

Comment: Yes, if I put a console.info in the answer block, I get the results. But I need to use those results in another method.

Comment: Please, post your result, in order to check data format.

Comment: Please check the publication update.

Comment: It seems you're not  awaiting the result of listarDptos in mounted. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513538/is-async-await-available-in-vue-js-mounted

Comment: thank you very much that solved my problem

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is \`async/await\` available in Vue.js \`mounted\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513538/is-async-await-available-in-vue-js-mounted)