# vue3 interpolated value not updating

Tags: vuejs3, vue-options-api

I am working in Vue 3 using the Options API.

My data is initially setting properly. However, when I requery my data after axios fetch, and set it to the data property `analytics`, I see it updating in the console log and in vue extension, but not in the template. Could someone point me in the right direction?

```js
<template>
{{analytics.analytics.daily_impression_data}}

</template>
export default {
    data() {
    return {
            analytics: {
                analytics: {
                    average: 0,
                    total: 0,
                    daily_impression_data: {},   
                },
            },
        }
    },
    async mounted() {
      
        await this.getAnalyticsData();
    },
    methods:
        async onSelectDate() {

            await this.getAnalyticsData();
        },
        async getAnalyticsData() { 
            Object.assign(this.options, this.parseQstring(this.$route.params.truck));
            const qstring = this.generateQstring();

            await Analytics.fetchAll(qstring).then((data) => {
                this.analytics = data;
            });
        },
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the full component code, including the template?

Comment: Here is the related code above

Comment: Is your question related to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53513538/is-async-await-available-in-vue-js-mounted. Unfortunately you haven't provided much context on what the methods do in your example.